Maas UEFI HTTPS or IPXE HTTPS Support
Is there any news if canonical MAAS supports https for loading the boot, config files or images. Unfortunately there is no overview of the supported boot types in the documentation.
I am looking for a way to transfer most of the data encrypted or is there a similar program that supports encryption better and has an equally comprehensive GUI or can be managed via the console.
In an old chat entry that there is no support
https://discourse.maas.io/t/http-boot-in-maas/1436
Now I am using WSL version 22.04 for experimenting with different tools, but in future it should be an real Ubuntu installation 22.04 or 24.04

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Now I am using WSL version 22.04 for experimenting with different tools, but in future it should be an real Ubuntu installation 22.04 or 24.04.
